# How to pass around some parameters to the URL in Cakephp2?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple site, and I want to add a parameter for some specific url in cakephp2 before transitioning to the other page.

Something like adding a parameter like `store_rank=sp` and `store_img=t` to some certain pages url.

How is it possible to do something like the following in cakephp2 ?

I think I will have to use something like $_GET but not sure how. Some tips or example will be great! I will love to hear from you!

I want to do something like the following:

```
(Home) 
    https: //localhost/mysite.com/main/page/
    ↓
    (Page for popluar stores) 
    https: //localhost/mysite.com/popular/view　←　"store_rank=sp" parameter should be passed to the /shops/page/id/
    ↓
    (poplar store page list)
    https: //localhost/mysite.com/shops/page/id/?store_rank=sp ←　"store_img=t" should be passed to /shops/page/details/
　　↓
    (One of the poplar store page)
    https: //localhost/mysite.com/shops/page/details/?store_rank=sp&store_img=t 
    ↓
    (contact form) 
    https: //localhost/mysite.com/shops/contact/form/ ←　Parameters should be removed in this page.
```

Comment: a quick look at this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046510/extract-url-value-with-cakephp-params

Comment: If possible I wanted to do it with $_GET?